# Migrating data from MongoDB to SQL Server, performance degrades over time 

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want transfer data from MongoDB to SQL Sever using the C# driver.
The data size is about 20,000,000 in three collections. I'm using 3 thread to
read it and 3 threads to insert into 3 different SQL Server tables.

After reading about 70,000,000 documents, the performance becomes
worse, the speed about one tenth of before, and network
bandwidth slumps.

How can I prevent performance from dropping off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try migrating each collection sequentially on a single thread.  The operation will be IO bound rather than CPU bound, so running it multi-threaded will more likely degrade performance and increase resource contention and context switching in the databases.

Also take a look at your SQL Server database disk writes.  It might be that the hard disk cache is being used but then writes slow down as the cache is flushed to disk.

Comment: Thank you, @Fulstow. For one collection, I use one thread to read from mongoDB, and one thread to insert the data into SQLServer.Network bandwidth about 50%, 4.2MB/s.The speed can keep about 10mins, then slump to about zero, <500KB/s.I think the IO bound is in reading data from mongoDB.

Comment: Do your SQL tables have any indexes? Could potentially slow down inserts over time.

Comment: The SQL tables has indexes. I use a bandwidth app to monitor the download and the upload speed.The download speed is the speed of reading data from mongoDB.It also slumps after about 10mins. I use cursor to enumrate the document from mongoDB.So I think the reason is the cursor has been destroyed because of timeout.

Comment: If it really is the cursor timing out you can work around that by setting a smaller batch size so that the client goes back to the MongoDB server more often. As long as the cursor is accessed before 10 minutes pass it will stay alive. If this scenario is correct it would imply that your bottleneck is SQL Server.